# DataGridView with drag and drop -- updating list based on user activity

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

A hobbyist trying to complete my first real app so thank you in advance and apologies if this is a noobie question.

I have a datagridview with Drag and Drop enabled populated with data from Team Class and a Dictionary which assigns a value to items in the List based on the index. I haven't implemented binding because I have not gotten it to work with drag and drop row re-ordering.

```
teamList = new List<Team>(){
    new Team("Redskins","WAS", "Washington"),
    new Team("Cowboys", "DAL", "Dallas"),
    new Team("Eagles", "PHI", "Philadelphia"),
    new Team("Giants", "NYG", "New York"),
    new Team("Packers", "GB", "Green Bay")
 };

class Team
{
    public string Mascot { get; private set; }
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
}

Dictionary<int, int> powerValues = new Dictionary<int, int>(){
    {1, 113},
    {2, 110},
    {3, 109},
    {4, 108},
    {5, 107}
};

private void printValues()
{   // add Team to DGV wiht PowerRank as index+1 and PowerValue based on Dictionary
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Team team in TeamList)
    {                
        // add all data to a datagrid view
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i+1, team.Mascot,powerValues[teamList.IndexOf(team) + 1]); //set the rank
        i++;
    }
}
```

Once I get to this point I am trying to do two things:

```
1) Update List<Team> based on drag and drop change
2) Re-assign PowerRank and PowerValue based on new index of Team
```

I have tried several things to no avail -- any ideas or points in the right direction?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620947/how-could-i-drag-and-drop-datagridview-rows-under-each-other) help?

Comment: I used that post to help implement the drag drop, but I still couldn't get it to work with a bound list -- doesn't support re-ordering. It also references re-assigning the "Priority" property but I don't see any details on how it was actually done.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten around #2 via a new method, but it isn't the elegant solution I was hoping for so open for improvements. Still working on #2

```
    private void reEstablishRanking()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < defaultPR.TeamList.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PowerRank"].Value = (i + 1);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["PowerValue"].Value = defaultPR.PRScores[i + 1];
        }
    }
```