# Drag&Drop: DataGridView rows "between" TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, drag-and-drop, tabcontrol

[Solved] I want to drag some DataGridViewRows from a DataGridView, contained in a TabPage, to another DataGridView also contained in another TabPage. I have set the DataGridView's Event ([How could I Drag and Drop DataGridView Rows under each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620947/how-could-i-drag-and-drop-datagridview-rows-under-each-other)), but i don't know how I can "navigate" between TabPages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bare bone example how I can drag text from one textbox on a tab to another one on a separate tab:

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.DoDragDrop(textBox1.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void tabControl1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Point location = tabControl1.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    for (int tab = 0; tab < tabControl1.TabCount; ++tab)
    {
        if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(tab).Contains(location))
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tab;
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void textBox2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void textBox2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
}
```

NOTE: You must set AllowDrop property to true on the TabControl, and of course on the destination control.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the question by myself (and @mrlucmorin) :

```
internal void dgv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
     List<DataGridViewRow> result = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
     foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows)
     {
         result.Add(row);
     }
     dgv.DoDragDrop(result, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void dgv_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

private void dgv_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
          DataGridView dataGridView1 = (DataGridView)sender;
          List<DataGridViewRow> rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
          rows = (List<DataGridViewRow>)e.Data.GetData(rows.GetType());

          //some stuff
     }
 }
```